# Windows 7/10 mouse clicks only work in some places and not others

Tags: windows-7, windows, mouse, windows-10

My son's Windows 7 (now 10) machine is exhibiting the following behavior:

- left clicks don't work everywhere
- the mouse movement is tracked everywhere and I can see hover events
- I can click on window handles (title bars), the taskbar, and the Start button
- I can't click on anything inside the Start menu or in the Settings/Control Panel (started using the keyboard)
- In Chrome, left clicking on a tab closes the tab rather than selecting it (I feel like this is a hint)
- I can click on links in Chrome webpages

Things I've tried:

- all updates (it auto updates every week)
- updated to Windows 10 (I was going to anyway)

  - the mouse didn't work in the Windows 10 "getting started" program either
- a different mouse: both are Logitech wireless mice, but of very different generations.
- every button on the mouse (though perhaps the buttons were remapped)
- double and triple clicking

Notes:

- My kids are 2 and 6, and it is highly probable that they could have changed a setting unintentionally.
- The account is **not** an Administrator
- It's an OEM Win 7 box from Dell (just over a year old)
- only Chrome and Minecraft installed. Nothing else.
- It gets automatic updates
- no internet use by the kids, they don't know how to use Chrome or IE, and I have those apps hidden (mostly)
- I *may* have parental mode settings turned on, can't recall.

Things I haven't tried yet (had to leave for work):

- (per another question's answer) Power off, plug in new mouse, unplug old mouse, power on.
- Safe mode
- Ubuntu live cd (to verify hardware), but I know the new mouse is good: it's the one I use.
- different brand mouse
- cabled, generic cheap dell mouse

Comment: Update [Logitech Set Point](http://support.logitech.com/en_us/downloads). I had the same issue after WIn10 update.

Comment: I'll try it. I don't have that installed, though.

Comment: I didn't when I first installed a clean Win 10 Insider. After going back & updating from Win7 to get my free upgrade, I again had the same issue. The latest Set Point fixed it on both occasions.

Comment: @Tetsujin Thanks, when I got home the mouse was mysteriously working. However, I installed Set Point and haven't had any problems since.

Comment: @Tetsujin Thanks, was having the same problems since the last week or so (I suspect because my new mouse came with an install of Logitech Options - even uninstalling it didn't fix the issue). Installing Set Point seems to have fixed it.